# Identifying parameters in HTTP request

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests

I am fairly proficient in Python and have started exploring the requests library to formulate simple HTTP requests. I have also taken a look at Sessions objects that allow me to login to a website and -using the session key- continue to interact with the website through my account.

Here comes my problem: I am trying to build a simple API in Python to perform certain actions that I would be able to do via the website. However, I do not know how certain HTTP requests need to look like in order to implement them via the requests library.

In general, when I know how to perform a task via the website, how can I identify:

- the type of HTTP request (GET or POST will suffice in my case)
- the URL, i.e where the resource is located on the server
- the body parameters that I need to specify for the request to be successful

Comment: Are you building urls that will request resources from servers you yourself have built / will build, or are you building urls to interact with other people's servers?

Comment: the latter, I am indeed trying to interact with an external server

Comment: is the server documented at all, or are you trying to hack / reverse engineer it? If it's the former, you just need to read the documentation to figure out when to use GET or POST requests, and what the body of POST requests should look like. If it's the latter, you're going to have a much harder time, but spend some time studying the structure of routes to which you have access, and `console.log(window)` in your browser's developer tools to look for global variable hints...

Comment: If you send the server address and tell us what specifically you're trying to do it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with python, but you can use a network proxy to examine your requests.

1. Download a network proxy like Burpsuite
2. Setup your browser to route all traffic through Burpsuite (default is localhost:8080)
3. Deactivate packet interception (in the Proxy tab)
4. Browse to your target website normally
5. Examine the request history in Burpsuite. You will find every information you need